# Pricing for the SubscribedSkus in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there any way for getting the Pricing for the SubscribedSkus in Microsoft Graph Api ,Like Billing Details how much a seat cost and date of the subscription took place.

I tried with Azure rest api but giving the Azure billing details but needed for the o365 billing Details like the plans we took while purchasing it

Comment: I'm not so sure but [Cost Management + Billing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/cost-management-billing-overview) can help. And it has [REST api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage?tabs=HTTP)

Comment: Yes I had seen this cost management is also for the AZURE subscription, if we don't have any Azure subscriptions I think it won't work and I'm checking for a different API for the 0365 Billing ... from my observations (https://admin.microsoft.com/fd/commerceapi/my-org/subscriptions?$expand=subscribedsku&optional=price, actions,transitiondetails,quickstarttag,cspsubscriptions) this is the call Used for subscriptions from Microsoft, I tried to decode it but didn't find anything please help me with this, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: cost management api seems only support Azure plan subscription. by the way, I really don't find other API for your requirement

Answer (score 0):

A bill is associated with the Azure subscription of the Azure Synapse or Azure Data Factory you are using. The price in this new billing model is based on the number of Microsoft Graph objects that you are accessing. For more information about billing : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/graph-data-connect/

Comment: Thanks for the advice but the azure billing is different from the subscriptions (Microsoft E3, Microsoft Teams Exploratory, etc.)we took, i tried the above that related to azure in Microsoft...